# segmentation fault while copying the string buffer

Tags: c, string, fault

i am getting seg fault in while copying the string. I have tried alternatives like, but same problem prevails.

```
#if 0
       struct msghdr {
               void *msg_name; /* Socket name */
               int msg_namelen; /* Length of name */
               struct iovec *msg_iov; /* Data blocks */
              __kernel_size_t msg_iovlen; /* Number of blocks */
              void *msg_control; /* Per protocol magic (eg BSD file descriptor passing) */
              __kernel_size_t msg_controllen; /* Length of cmsg list */
              unsigned int msg_flags;
};
#endif


void call(char sendString[] )
{
    struct msghdr msg;
    int rc;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0 , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&msg, 0 , sizeof(struct msghdr));
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&server_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    printf("sendString = %s\n", sendString);
    //msg.msg_iov->iov_base = (void *)sendString; // seg fault here
    memcpy(msg.msg_iov->iov_base, sendString, strlen(sendString)); // seg fault here
    printf("len = %d\n", strlen(sendString));
    #if 0
    msg.msg_iov->iov_len = strlen(sendString);
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;
    msg.msg_flags = 0;
    #endif
    printf("rc = %d\n", rc);
```

}

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    char buff[32] = "Hello\0";
    call(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried both the cases, and getting segmentation fault in both lines :

```
msg.msg_iov->iov_base = (void *)sendString;
memcpy(msg.msg_iov->iov_base, sendString, strlen(sendString));
```

appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg.msg_iov` is a pointer and there is no memory allocated for this pointer and you are trying to dereference it which will lead to undefined behavior.

Before doing a `memcpy()` do

```
msg.msg_iov = malloc(sizeof(struct iovec));
```

You haven't shown the `struct iovec` definition so I assume member `iov_base` within it has enough space to hold the string(`sendString`).

Comment: Thanks, i missed out that point.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar np ...